# Can a web app be made to act like an Android/iPhone app?

Tags: android, iphone, google-chrome, web-applications, push-notification

I'm using Linkedin Pulse and to refresh it I unconsciously pulled down the screen when I was at the top of the newsfeed. The Google Chrome refresh symbol appeared when I did this. This made me wonder - is this app just a viewport to a mobile website opened by my default browser (Chrome)? Is it possible to make phone apps that are really just the user using their internet browser? This would save me a lot of development time. Also, if this is possible, can your phone still receive push notifications through this pseudo-mobile app?

Answer (score 3):

I have made several applications which to the user appear to be a native app but really are just web pages using safari.

Apple support this well with the safari browser. It allows you to create an app on the home screen with custom icon, orientation, removing scroll bars and fixed views. All the options are on here ([Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html))

Android is a bit different. You can achieve the same thing with Chrome. If you save a site with `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` in the header it will open it in full screen.

As far as I am aware web apps cannot push notification to the user. This has to be done in native apps however there is an app called [pushover](https://pushover.net/) which you can user as a middle man.